# HTML form not submitting to remote server

Tags: php, html, forms, server, ip

I have an HTML form which I'm trying to connect to php code on a remote server

```
 <form action="http://111.111.11.111/my-api/someServerSideCode.php" method="post">
    <!--some inputs and such-->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But it won't submit! Am I using `action` wrong or perhaps do I have the wrong link format?

I've tried pasting the link into a browser and it works fine (the php code executes and something is written to my database), but for some reason it won't fire in the form

Any help would be greatly appreciated

> *note: the link above is obviously manipulated and won't work*

Comment: Have you watched in the developer console what happens when you click submit?

Comment: Where do I look? nothing comes up in the console :/

Comment: The `network` tab would show if something is being sent out. The `console` tab might show errors you are encountering, check them both. Also use `preserve log` incase the page is being reloaded for some reason.

Comment: Nothing doing on either tab. I'm using Stripe (a payment API), so there's a whole lotta data from there, but nothing about my server

Comment: The backend shouldn't matter. This is client side, it should at least attempt to submit. I just did a test on w3's editor and got back `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://111.111.11.111/my-api/someServerSideCode.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` (not to say that is your issue, just showing that something should come out)

Comment: changing the link to https didn't help either

Comment: Your form code is good. Check for typos. A good web debugger I like to use is Fiddler. Try with a different browser or try restarting your local server. I ran into weird issues many times that I couldn't explain but they were solved by restarting my either my computer or services.